# Toggle time series on/off with highcharts R

Tags: r, highcharts

I am using highstock with highcharts R api. https://jkunst.com/highcharter/articles/stock.html
I have multiple time series on my graph and I would like a way to toggle them on and off like in the usual hchart() function. Below is a reproducible example. I would like to be able to toggle on and off the blue line.

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
getSymbols(c("SPY", 'QQQ'))

highchart(type = "stock") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Charting some Symbols") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Data extracted using quantmod package") %>% 
  hc_add_series(Cl(SPY), id = "spy", name = "SPY") %>% 
  hc_add_series(Cl(QQQ), id = "qqq", name = "QQQ")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely what you mean and how it should work? Do you just want to turn on the legend options?

Comment: @madepiet I think that would do it. I basically want to have the feature seen in this graph here. Where you can click on and off the chart. https://jkunst.com/highcharter/articles/highcharts-api.html

Comment: Then all you have to do is turn on this legend: `hc_legend(enabled = "true")`

Comment: this worked, thank you